# Ethernet speed issue

Tags: ethernet, speed

We have made a customized harness cable for Ethernet communication as shown in the attached image. Here we are facing an issue with communication speed.

Whenever we use the below cable, we get only 10 Mbps with auto-negotiation, and when we cut the cable at the end of C1 which is going to the C2 end we get 100 Mbps.

What could be the reason? Will splitting the Ethernet cable and connecting to both ends of the connector affect the Ethernet speed?

Is Ethernet communication recommending only point-to-point communication?
How to avoid the speed reduction in the below cable harness?

[image]

Comment: "Is Ethernet communication recommending only point-to-point communication?" -- Well, that depends on what we mean with "Ethernet" exactly... I.e. if you're using 10BASE5 (the original Ethernet) or 10BASE2 ("thin Ethernet"), then it's an actual multi-drop bus. But then again, that would be using coaxial cable, limited to 10 Mb/s and you'd have to live in the 1980's or 90's. With 10BASE-T, hubs were common, making it look effectively like a bus, though still with an active device at both ends (two) of the cable.

Comment: What's your goal here ?  To sniff the traffic on the wire?   If so you need either a "monitor port" on a switch, or you could get away with an old-school ethernet hub that sprays all frames out all interfaces.   (comment cos doesn't answer question)

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be using standard 10Base-T and 100Base-TX.

These require point-to-point twisted pair connections between devices.

The cable or wire harness from "C1" connector cannot route Ethernet to both "C2" and the "RJ45" connectors.

Having a cable like that means you have one device always correctly placed at one end of a cable, one device always incorrectly placed in the middle of a cable, and always one unterminated one meter stub causing signal reflections in the cable.

Apparently 1 meter stub like that is enough to make 100Base-TX connection to fail.

There may be other errors as well.

Ethernet connections needs impedance controlled twisted pairs to work properly. If you are not using 100 ohm twisted pair cabling with correctly connected signal and return as a twisted pair, that will further make the situation worse.

Answer (score 3):

Ethernet requires point to point connections*, the poor performance is likely due to the incorrect termination in the middle of a cable.

Typically you will want an ethernet switch in between the two devices

*Excluding old standards, the current standard is IEEE 802.3 I believe